Is there a way to view all the registered nodes that the ShedLock is operating on?
I am currently using ShedLock in my Java Spring Boot application to lock the task to be only executing on a single node(Instance). I have this application deployed to multiple servers (4 to be precise) and the logs show that when the schedule comes it only executes on one of those 4 servers.
But maybe there is a way to view the list of all nodes that specific @SchedulerLock with specific name exists on ?
I think that would be very convenient even if you know the name of servers that you have deployed the application on.
